# Access public static variable from another script Unity

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, static, public

I am trying to access and change of the value of a variable from another script, I have watched various different tutorial on youtube but cannot seems to do it. It always come up with an error as following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GlobalValues : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static bool c2u;

}
```

And the other script

```
public class Choosing : MonoBehaviour {
private void Start()
{
    GlobalValues.c2u = false;
}
}
```

In the "Choosing" script, the GlobalValues always shows "'GlobalValues' does not exist in this current context". What can i do to fix this problem

Comment: provide import section in Choosing.cs as mentioned in answer. By the way MonoBehaviour as parent is not necessary for GlobalValues. And one more point - use Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work fine. The only way I could see it not working is if you haven't saved one of the scripts.

Comment: Or if its namespace isn't imported.